# Eclipse-Latex-Building problem

Tags: errors, miktex, windows, eclipse

I've just installed MikText and the TeXlipse 1.5.0 plugin on Eclipse.
On this photo you can see the Builder settings:
[image]

Im getting this error, when I try to build the file:

[image]

I am also getting en error in Eclipse- it says: "Emergency stop.\end{document}(followed by:) 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Make sure your PDF isn't open in adobe reader. It (and some other readers) lock the file on view.

Comment: Thx for the fast answer. I have all my pdf-Readers closed before I build the file. What do you mean by "lock the file on view"

Comment: A big problem in state machines is that of concurrent editing; many pieces of software (sometimes, even the OS) will 'lock' the file so that no other programs (eg. LaTeX) can write to it.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. Unfortunately that's not the problem here...As I sad, I always close all pfd-Reader before I build the file

Comment: Try cleaning the project (ie. deleting every file you did not personally create).  There's nothing in the screenshot you posted that would cause a problem.

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt fix my problem...

Comment: I have solved the problemd. The problem was FoxitReader. I closed it before I build the project but just closing is not enough...you have to kill the process in the task-manager every time you want to build...That's why I switched to Summatra-PDF because it really get closed without needing to kill the process